# protractor: how to confirm fs.watch was called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous, protractor

I am doing e2e testing and I am checking if a folder is being modified with this code:

```
var watchEvent = false;
fs.watch('/tmp/directory', function(event, folderName) {
    watchEvent = true;
    console.log("it entered watch");
    if (event === "rename" && folderName === currentDirectory) {
        console.log("my directory changed");
    };
});
expect(watchEvent).toBe(true, "My directory didn't change");
```

Now I tested it, and it actually works, when the directory changes, it goes into the watch listener, prints the `"it entered watch"` and `"my directory changed"` but as this call is asynchronous `watchEvent` doesn't change in time and the `expect` returns `false`.

Now when it doesn't work (so the directory doesn't change) it doesn't print `"it entered watch"` and also the `expect` returns `false`.

I am thinking of 2 alternatives:

- There is a way I can catch when the watch didn't change at all (and how is that working? how much time is it waiting?)
- There is a way I can trigger an event when a variable changes (a promise?) so for example I could have:

  ```
  var watchEvent;
  // 1. watch event is called, and assigns true.
  // 2. wait for a promise to confirm that `watchEvent` has a value and 
  // run the `expect inside`
  ```

**P.S.** I also don't fully understand how `fs.watch` is waiting for my folder to change, when does it end? why is my test finishing if nothing happened?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

1. fs.watch() takes an argument (persistent: true|false) which can control whether the watch should continue to watch the entity, for ever.
2. If the requirement is to assert whether a watch event indeed changed your file or not, then you can actually bring the assertion code inside the watch callback.
3. If the requirement is to assert whether a watch event indeed happened or not, that has to be timebound - for example, you can use setTimeout to setup a timer of your choice, and inside the timer function you could assert.
4. If the requirement is to check whether a file is changed or not (assess the correctness of the watch function), then you have to do the assertion manually, cannot depend on the watch function itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 2. I can setup the expect inside the watch, but it won't run if the directory didn't change

Comment: 1. Documentation says that 'persistent' is by default true

Comment: 3. A code example here would be help a lot, and 4. I don't understand what you mean here